# Inserting output from Pandas Dataframe to a Redshift table

Tags: pandas, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I am trying to insert an output obtained from Pandas Dataframe into Redshift table using `insert` option. Given below is how my data is:

```
dwh_cur.execute("""select max(created_at) from table_name""")
df = dwh_cur.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['max_date']) <<-- Pandas output
```

I am trying to have the above output inserted into the Redshift table using the below query:

```
dwh_cur.execute("""insert into new_table values('table_name', max_date)""")
```

I am getting an error

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "max_date" does not exist in new_table
```

Given below is how `new_table` structure is:

```
table_name, max_date
```

Comment: the error message says max_date is not in table.  could u check the database, confirm the tables, and check spellings ? the error pretty much says it all. so I think that's where the focus should be. i assume the table already exists in the database

Comment: @sammywemmy yes the table and column do exist. Just that when I perform the insert query it does not seem to take the value from the DataFrame output and store it in the `max_date` column in the target table

Comment: also, i dont think u r inserting the data via pandas. that's y i didnt refer to it earlier. usually, pandas has to_sql method. y is the table name in quotes? is it just one column in the table? trying to see why psycopg is giving u that error if the column already exists

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you meant to do: Get the `max_date` for the corresponding table from your first query and then insert it into a new table where you have various table names as one column and the corresponding `max_date`s as another column.

Getting the max_date of table_name:

```py
max_date = df["max_date"][0]
```

Using string interpolation here to construct the insert statement with the `max_date` value. This will make use of the `max_date` you just got from your first query.

```py
dwh_cur.execute(f"insert into new_table (table_name, max_date) values(table_name, {max_date})")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.